# Image Processing; find transformation matrix (Rot, Trans)

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, image-processing

Hopefully this is a simple question; linear algebra is not my strong suit.

I am correlating two greyscale images based on their unique values (0-255) and the position of said values in matrix form. I have separated each image into multiple matrices based on corresponding greyscale values found in both images.

I am trying to re-align the images based on the translation/rotation of these greyscale values from image to image.

My question then; given two matrices (images)

Matrix A for greyscale value (50) = ([5,3],[4,8],[2,1],[0,9])

Matrix B for greyscale value (50) = ([2,2],[7,14],[4,3],[5,10])

Can I find a matrix of transformation such that we can extract a translation matrix and rotation matrix?

Edit: Sorry these are just example matrices, they will all be nx2 matrices, though I am considering padding out the matrices with zeros to make it nxn - will that help?

Comment: I have no knowledge of image processing myself, but just as a tip (which you may already know), there's also a Stack Exchange about signal processing (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). In case you don't find what you're looking for here, maybe they can help over there. :)

Comment: You want to find such $4\times 4$ rotation matrix $R$ and $4 \times 2$ matrix $T$ such that $B = R.A+T$? Please clarify.

Comment: thanks @Kevin, I will do if I get no luck here, though it is the maths on how to perform this operation I wish to know.

Comment: @Veliko, added clarification regarding matrix type. Theses are 2D matrices, x/y coordinates, rotation matrix will be of type ([cos(T), -sin(T), 0],[sin(T), cos(T), 0], [0,0,1])

Comment: It seems to me your "$n\times2$ matrices" are just lists of $(x,y)$ coordinate pairs and have nothing to do with anything that is an $n\times2$ matrix in any useful mathematical sense. I second the recommendation to seek help from people who have expertise specifically in signal processing or image processing; also, don't get too attached to the idea of separating the image into those  "$n\times2$ matrices"; be open to other ideas.

Comment: As I googled, I think I realized what you need. Every row is a 2D point. So "rotation" and "translation" are performed to EVERY row. So given two sets of points written in the matrices $A$ and $B$ you want to find a rotation matrix $R = \left(\begin{matrix} \cos{T} & -\sin{T} \\ \sin{T} & \cos{T} \end{matrix}\right)$ and a translation vector $tr = (t_x, t_y)^t$ such that for every row $B_i$ of $B$ and every row $A_i$ of $A$ you have $B_i = R.A_i^t + tr$.

Comment: @Veliko; that appears to be the solution I need, I'm not sure how to solve this but I'll give it a try. If I can solve one I can solve them all yes?

Comment: @vanoccupanther check my answer, I provide you with an algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I googled, I think I realized what you need. Every row is a 2D point. So "rotation" and "translation" are performed to EVERY row. So given two sets of points written in the matrices $A$ and $B$ you want to find a rotation matrix $R = \left(\begin{matrix} \cos{T} & -\sin{T} \\ \sin{T} & \cos{T} \end{matrix}\right)$ and a translation vector $tr = (t_x, t_y)^t$ such that for every row $B_i$ of $B$ and every row $A_i$ of $A$ you have $B_i^t = R.A_i^t + tr$.

Now, if $R$ and $tr$ exist and if you have two distinct rows from $B$ and $A$ you will have that

$$ B_1^t = R.A_1^t+tr, \qquad B_2^t = R.A_2^t+tr$$

from where after subtraction you will obtain $B_2^t-B_1^t = R.(A_2^t-A_1^t)$ which is a $2\times 2$ linear system for the "variables" $\cos{T}$ and $\sin{T}$. If your points are distinct, you will obtain unique solution for $R$ (and you know that an angle $T$ is determined uniquely by its $\sin$ and $\cos$).  Once you have $R$ determined you obtain $tr$ from the first equation: $tr = B_1^t-R.A_1^t$.

Comment: Thanks @Veliko, much appreciated.

Comment: I calculated the rotation angle and translation for row1, could you confirm I'm calculating this correctly: trans_vector = [Rot(80.92), Trans(8.81, 3.69)]. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I calculated that correctly

Comment: @vanoccupanther , are you sure that each row is coordinates of a point in 2D? Your "matrices" don't hold information about color, right?

Answer (score 0):

I made a plot of your two sets of points (if that is really the meaning of the matrices $A$ and $B$)
The red points are the points from $A$ and the blue ones from $B$. For this two examples it is not true that there exists a rotational matrix $R$ and a translating vector $tr$ such that $B_i^t = R.A_i^t+tr$ as I proposed in the previous answer.

[image]

So I guess that either the question remained unclear after the comments or the data is bad.

Comment: thanks for following up on this. Initially I was thinking to create a line of best fit for each value and then comparing it to the same value in the next image, but while that would give me rotation it wouldn't give me a translation. I therefore came looking for a simple way to include both a rotation and translation.

Comment: and to answer your question above, no all images are greyscale values between 0-255. There are a number of solutions out there with regards to taking fft's of keypoints in each image etc but I'm looking for something different I suppose.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't help. Actually arbitrary (not only through the center)  line in 2D can be transformed to every other via a sequence of translation, rotation and translation again.

Comment: you've helped a great deal, one more thing if its ok to ask, how would I go about getting an average translation value between individual values of successive images? _Im_1 val 50_ trans to _Im_2 val 50_. If I attempt to get every translation between each point in successive images I'll end up with a zero translation, I possibly could look at values that have zero euclidean distance in one image, count the pixels and try find the corresponding values (with error rates due to change etc) in the next image.